# Plotting a scaled version of a variable using ggplot2. Need to show the scale too

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series, visualization

I am trying to plot a variable over time using `ggplot2`.

My current plot looks like this:

[image]

However, I want the `scaled values` with `significant numbers` shown on the `axis`. The scale needs to be shown at the top left corner. Something like:-

[image]

I don't want to scale the plot. The `axis` needs to show the `significant numbers` and the `exponential scale` needs to be shown at the top left.

Comment: I'm sure there was a question on how to do that a few months ago but I can't find it, maybe someone else does?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you had in mind (my own MWE):

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame( x=rnorm(10), y=seq(1e8,10e8,by=1e8))

p <- ggplot(df)+
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y/1e8))+
  geom_text(aes(x=-Inf,y=Inf,label=as.character(paste("10^8"))), parse=T, hjust=1, vjust=0.8, size=5/14*10)+
  scale_y_continuous(name="y")

gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name == "panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)
```

Basically divide by the exponent, and then write it manually at the top left. The parse=T renders the power as an actual power. That factor of 5/14 was mentioned on another post as being the rough factor by which geom_text size relates to the size you set text to be elsewhere on the graph (no idea why but I've found doing 5/14*text-size-you-want gives a decent looking geom_text). Finally the last three lines prevent the off-plot-panel text being cropped out (you wouldn't see the geom_text otherwise). Hope this gives you something to work with.

Comment: This should work but manually dividing by 10^8 must not be the right way to do this